# Trying to access an index from a list and convert it into a string in python

Tags: python, list

I have a program that I'm writing for a computer class, and I'm having a little bit of trouble accessing the index value of something. I'm fairly new to python (I have only been using it for a week) and I need this program to work successfully.
I've already tried other posts and have used content from other posts, but I'm still struggling with trying to make my program work. I hope this is enough to work with.

I want to print the corresponding index to each item in the "tasks" list at the bottom "wModt" spot. I've tried asking one of the instructors but I was still confused. I want the tasks to be chosen in the index order 0, 1, 2, etc. and then repeat. Please help!

Here is some of my code.

```
workers = ['Jim','Bob','Matt','Brian','Evan','Alan','Gary','Henry','Noah']

tasks = ['Drilling','Digging','Filling','Pouring']

...

while len(workers) > 0:
    wModt = num_workers % num_tasks

    working = random.choice(workers)
    workers.remove(working)
    num_workers -= 1

    for idx, val in enumerate(tasks):
        pass

    print working + "'s job is", wModt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to do something like this is to zip your lists together ... you can make something repeat by using itertools cycle

```
from itertools import cycle
for worker,job in zip(workers,cycle(tasks)):
    #do something with them
```

you could likewise make a dictionary mapping workers to jobs

```
datamap = dict(zip(workers,cycle(tasks))
print datamap["Jim"]
```

that said you can easily get the index of something by asking

```
jims_index = workers.index("Jim")
```